# Google Weather API returns HTTP 403 Error

Tags: http-status-code-403, weather-api, google-weather-api

I use the Google weather API in my web site, and today I get an error that the API link doesn't return any data.

When I check the link directly I get an (Error 403).

[Here is the link](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Cairo-Egypt&hl=en).

Can anyone please tell me a solution for this and provide me another link for the API?

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every now and then the API stops working for short periods of time, the last days more often a 403 is trown. For my site, last night it happened 13 times. But the site tries immediately again and the second or third time, the data loads without problems. As the API is unofficial, not sure what’s causing the 403.

Make sure you cache the data as the API will block your IP temporary when you make too much requests. In my case, I cache for 20 minutes and if no data can retrieved, the site will not try more than 10 times to reload the API. Once I forgot to turn caching on after debugging and as my site did many hundred requests (with every visitor), the IP was blocked within an hour. If a remember correct, the error was not a 403. Fortunately, the block lasts for less than a half day.

Comment: I cached the xml for 15 mins, the problem solved and happened again

Comment: Unfortunatly, it seems the weather API is shut down by Google. I will look at another service like Yahoo or Worldweatheronline, both have a free (although somewhat limited) API.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an intermittent 403 Forbidden response to the Google Weather API that you are using. See [Google Weather API 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878143/google-weather-api-403-error/)

The reason for the intermittent 403 response is not known but has been a problem since the 7th of August 2012.

Comment: I just started having the problem yesterday, August 9th. I'm getting a 403 error.

Comment: Please refer to the linked issue above. It's still relevant.