# simplexml_load_string parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am getting the below error when parsing google weather. Anyone know a solution for this been looking everywhere but no joy

```
Entity: line 2: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected

    $lang ='English';
    $place=urlencode($weather);
    $place = utf8_encode($place);
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather='.$place.',$&hl='.$lang.'';        

    $ch = curl_init();       
    //Set CURL options
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    $raw_data = curl_exec($ch);
    //close CURL cause we dont need it anymore
    curl_close($ch);         

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($raw_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The google weather API [is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851659/google-weather-api-http-403-error) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878143/google-weather-api-403-error) throw 403 errors from time to time. When that happens, the request will be answered with an HTTP 403 response and an HTML error document. Since the error document is not valid XML, you cannot parse it with `simplexml_load_string`.

You should use [another weather API](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/).

Comment: why have they been disabled. If you click the link you can see there is data available.

Comment: it was working fine about a month ago- i still get data back from the link you provided

Comment: @MatthewChambers Oh, you're right. It hasn't been disabled (I thought it would be one of the  [ones deprecated in 2012](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.de/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html)). It just returns 403 errors from time to time. Currently, I get a consistent 403 from three different IPs.